# Docker -m parameter limit usage of IPC shared memory

Tags: c++, docker, shared-memory

I run a docker container with parameter `-m 100m` and `--ipc host`, and inside container run a program using IPC shared memory. when I write data more than `100m` into shared memory, the program OOMKilled. I want to known if docker memory limitation include the usage of shared memory and why.

My Docker version 1.12

My Docker run command

```
docker run -idt -m 100m --ipc host --name ipc_test centos:7 bash
```

My program using IPC shared memoey.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <error.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#define SIZE 1024*1024*1024
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int shmid ;
    char *shmaddr ;
    struct shmid_ds buf ;
    int flag = 0 ;
    int pid ;
    shmid = shmget(15672000, SIZE, IPC_CREAT ) ;

    if ( shmid < 0 )
    {
        cout << "get shm ipcid failed" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    cout << "shmid: " << shmid << endl;
    shmaddr = (char *)shmat( shmid, NULL, 0 ) ;

    cout << "shmaddr:" <<  &shmaddr << endl;
    string a = "";
    string b = "1231231231"; // 10
    int c = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j< 10; j++)
    {
        cout << j << endl;
        for(int i = 0; i < 1024*1024; i++)
        {
            a += b;
        }
        strcpy( shmaddr, a.c_str());
        shmaddr += a.length();
        c += a.length();
        cout << a.length() << endl;
        a.clear();
    }
    shmdt( shmaddr ) ;
    return 0 ;
}
```